# react-table adds reference on row click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-table

I'm currently facing the following issue: I'm working on a react web app which contains one component that displays products that are contained in the products array state. A product can be added by clicking on a table row of a react-table which contains different products. A product can be added multiple times by clicking on the same product.

```
getTdProps={(state, rowInfo, column, instance) => {
              return {
                onClick: (e, handleOriginal) => {
                  that.props.handleProductSelect(rowInfo.original);
                }
              };
            }}
```

If a table row is clicked, the handleProductSelect function is called which passes the original data as parameter.

```
handleProductSelect(oSelProduct) {
    oSelProduct["amount"] = 1;
    oSelProduct["selectedVariantOptions"] = [];
    this.setState(
      prevStates => ({
        products: [...prevStates.products, oSelProduct]
      }),
      () => {
        ...
      }
    );
  }
```

The selected product will be added to the products array, the component will be re-rendered and the products will be shown in a standard html table.

Each rendered product contains a plus and minus button to change the amount of each product. The plus button e.g. calls the handlePlusButton function:

```
handlePlusButton(i) {
    this.setState(state => {
      const products = state.products.map((product, j) => {
        if (j === i) {
          product.amount = product.amount + 1;
          return product;
        } else {
          return product;
        }
      });
      return {
        products
      };
    });
  }
```

Problem: If I click on the same product multiple times, they will be added to the product array. Now if I click on the plus button to change the amount, somehow the amount will be changed for all products which where added. So somehow it looks like a reference is added to the products array. How can I avoid this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem happens, becuase You are adding two references to the same product.
Try to change `handleProductSelect` to this:

```
handleProductSelect(oSelProduct) {
    const newProduct = {
       ...oSelProduct,
       amount: 1,
       selectedVariantOptions: []
    };

    this.setState(
      prevStates => ({
        products: [...prevStates.products, newProduct]
      }),
      () => {
        ...
      }
    );
  }
```